# ExtJs Message box with Custom buttons

Tags: extjs, extjs3

How to display ExtJS Message box with Custom buttons.

I want a Message box with a Custom message and "Cancel" and "Deactivate" Buttons.
Please give some idea.

```
buttons: [{
    text: "Cancel",
    handler: function () {
        Ext.MessageBox.hide();
        //submitTicketForm();
    }
},{
    text: "Deactivate",
    handler: function () {
        Ext.MessageBox.hide();
    }
}],
```

I am using it like this but not getting any buttons.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MessageBox is an single instance of an internally managed Window used for prompt, show, alert, etc.

You can change the buttonText by passing in a string for show like this:

```
buttons: {ok: "Foo", cancel: "Bar"}
```

Refer : 
[MessageBox](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/source/MessageBox.html#method-Ext.MessageBox-show)

```
buttons: { 
                ok: "Foo", 
                handler: function(){ 
                    Ext.MessageBox.hide(); 

                },
                cancel: "Bar",
                handler: function(){
                    Ext.MessageBox.hide();
                }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay..its working fine,but how to add handler ,when iam trying to add handler for one button,buttons are not getting........thanks

Comment: add this : `fn : function(btn){  console.log('btn'+btn);}`

Comment: I think it's important to note that the `buttons` property is only available when you create a new message box. If you're using `Ext.Msg.show({config})` there is no `button` property!

Answer (score 16):

In ExtJS 4, you can make your own component like this:

```
Ext.define('App.view.MyDialog', {
    /**
     * Shows the dialog.
     */
    show: function() {
        var dialog = Ext.create('Ext.window.MessageBox', {
            buttons: [{
                text: 'baz',
                iconCls: 'icon-add',
                handler: function() {
                    dialog.close();
                }
            }]
        });

        dialog.show({
            title: 'foo!',
            msg: '<p>bar?</p>',
            icon: Ext.MessageBox.WARNING
        });

        dialog.setHeight(160);
        dialog.setWidth(420);
    }
});
```

then:

```
var dialog = Ext.create('App.view.MyDialog');
dialog.show();
```

Comment: You defining a class and create a component within. Why not just extend a Messagebox?

Answer (score 2):

Use 'buttonText' instead of 'button',

```
buttonText: {ok: 'Deactivate', cancel: 'Cancel'},
fn: function(btn) {
    if (btn === 'ok') {
        Ext.MessageBox.hide();
    }  else {
        Ext.MessageBox.hide(); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In ExtJS 4 and ExtJS 5, to set custom text for buttons you need to use both `buttons` and `buttonText` configs:

```
buttons: [{
    Ext.Msg.OK
}],
buttonText: { 
    ok: "Custom text"
},
fn: function() { 
    // ...handle OK button
}
```